# how to count field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K \subset L \subset M $ is a tower of fields and let $ \sigma:L \hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{K}}$,Where $\overline K$ is algebraic closure of $K$.
My questions is how to show $\sigma$ extends in exactly $ [M:L]$ ways to a field embedding $ M\hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{K}}$.

Comment: This isn't true without more assumptions.

Comment: Seems to me that you need $M/L$ to be separable for this to hold. Possibly also finite, but my brain is somewhat impaired at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is false without further assumptions. If $M$ is a finite extension of $L$, then a necessary and sufficient condition for this to be true is that $M$ is separable.

If $M$ is finite and separable, then by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) it can be written $L[\alpha]/f(a)$ where $f$ is an irreducible separable polynomial over $L$. Hence the $L$-linear maps $M \to \overline{L}$ (if $L$ embeds $K$-linearly into $\bar{K}$ then $\overline{L} = \overline{K}$ anyway) correspond to the roots of $f$ over $\overline{L}$, of which there are $\deg f = [M : L]$ by separability.

By contrast, consider the following example of a (purely) inseparable extension. Let $L = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and let $M = L[\alpha]/(\alpha^p - t)$. Over $\overline{L}$ we have

$$\alpha^p - t = (\alpha - \sqrt[p]{t})^p$$

since we are working in characteristic $p$, and hence this polynomial has a unique root over $\overline{L}$. So there is only one $L$-linear embedding of $M$ into $\overline{L}$.